# el-select shows options horizontally. Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

I'm switching from vue.js to vue3 and also with element-ui to element-plus.
But the behavior of el-select is too strange: it shows the option horizontally like a wrappanel.
What class or style responsible for this? I want usual dropdownlist )

```
<el-select placeholder="year" v-model="filter.year" clearable v-on:clear="filter.year = null">
    <el-option v-for="y in years" :key="y" :value="y" :label="y" />
</el-select>`
```

filter.year - it is a simple list of integers

I read all documentation about el-select. There are no option for this behavior.

[scr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ycNP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten the Element+ css?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css" />
```

Here is the working playground

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const App = {
data() {
    return {
      filter: { year: null},
      years: [1991, 1992, 1993]
    };
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css" />
   <div id="app" v-cloak>
    <el-select placeholder="year" v-model="filter.year" clearable v-on:clear="filter.year = null">
      <el-option v-for="y in years" :key="y" :value="y" :label="y" />
    </el-select>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, still not working. I think, conflict of styles is reason of this behaviour.

I written simple ul/li list and it show by same way.

This is section of my package json. Nothing criminal.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.29.1",
    "element": "^0.1.4",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
```